# Prompt fb login not just show the login button

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have read many different articles and seen samples that check for fb login status. I have a working page built from these educational resources.

My question however is if I can cut straight to the login prompt saving the user from having to click on the login button.

Currently I have the Login Button in a div and hidden:

```
<div id="fblogin">
   .......
   class="fb-login-button"
   onlogin="afterFbLogin()"
   data-show-faces="false"
   data-width="200"
   data-max-rows="1"
   data-scope="publish_stream">
   ........
</div>
```

Currently FB.Init runs on page load and checks the login status and shows the div if needed. The user then clicks the login button....then after login has to click the share button which is OK I guess.

It would be my preference however to have a slightly different flow.

1. On page load I don't want fb.init to display the login button.
2. When they click on the share button then check value of hidden field. If they are loggid in post as normal. If not jump straight to login prompt.

So for #1. I just changed the FB.getLoginStatus if/then/else branch for not_authorized and unknown to set the value of a hidden input type.

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {

   if (response.status === 'connected') 
   {
      ....code....
   }
   else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') 
   {
      document.getElementById('FbLoginStatus').value = 'not_authorized';
   }
   else 
   {
      document.getElementById('FbLoginStatus').value = 'unknown';
   }
});
```

For #2. The fb sdk loads the login button (when init above detects not logged in) as below but if I code to this (in javascript find this element and execute click) and facebook changes their sdk my code could then break.

```
<div tabindex="0" class="pluginFaviconButton pluginFaviconButtonEnabled pluginFaviconButtonMedium" id="u_0_0" role="button">
```

So any input on step 1 and any ideas on how to accomplish step two using the sdk would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The best way I think to move forward is to simply use a variable to see get a user's login status as soon as facebook has initialized, and use that to set a boolean variable that determines whether to login or share immediately.

So let's take a look at this step by step:

## loggedIn Variable

First we'll want to declare the bool so we have access to it and set it to false by default. You'll probably want to put this somewhere inside the head.

```
var loggedIn = false;
```

## Original Facebook Init Template

Next, let's take a look at the basic Facebook init template (let me know if you're using something different):

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        // init the FB JS SDK
        FB.init({
            appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
            channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel file for x-domain comms
            status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
            xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
        });

        // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
    };

    // Load the SDK asynchronously
    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

## Add FB.getLoginStatus()

After the following line:

```
// Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
```

we'll want to check the user's login status with the following function:

```
// See if the User is logged in
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected')
    {
        // Mark the user as logged in
        loggedIn = true;
    }
});
```

## Test loggedIn Before Sharing

I don't know what your code for sharing on facebook looks like, but let's pretend you put it into a function called `fbShare()`. What we can do now is assign the onclick function of `tryShare()` to your Share Button, and define the function with something like the following logic:

```
function tryShare()
{
    if (loggedIn)
    {
        //User is already logged in and authorized
        fbShare();
    }
    else
    {
        // Pop open the FB Login dialog
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                // Successful login/auth
                fbShare();
            }
            else
            {
                // Your user didn't want to log in to fb
            }
        });
    }
}
```

## Summary

So your code should ultimately look something like the following:

```
<head>
...
<script ... >
...
function fbShare()
{
    // Your sharing code goes here
}

var loggedIn = false;

function tryShare()
{
    // tryShare() function immediately above this..
}
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        // init the FB JS SDK
        FB.init({
            appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
            channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel file for x-domain comms
            status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
            xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
        });

        // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
        
        // See if the User is logged in
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected')
            {
                // Mark the user as logged in
                loggedIn = true;
            }
        });
    };

    // Load the SDK asynchronously
    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
...
<button onclick="tryShare()">Share on Facebook</button>
```

Most of this code besides `tryShare()` is directly copied from the [Facebook JavaScript SDK Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/). Let me know if this all makes sense :)

Comment: bit of a dumb question here. FB.init runs automatically on page load (not sure how that happens but it does). If I run it a second time I get an error in the debug console about it already having been run/loaded. I see some people say to use FB._initialized = false; and then rerun it but I'm not sure that is what you were thinking. I have edited my OP with code snippets if they are of any value to you for seeing what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @user1278561 not a dumb question at all :) It's actually completely my fault because I gave a horrible answer (I can see how "do fb init" can be a bit unclear lol). I updated/changed my answer, because my initial solution wasn't a good one even if it would have been clearly communicated lol. Let me know if the new answer works/makes sense or not :)